# Open blob file stored in indexDB on ios/Ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, indexeddb

Hello i download file using axios like so.

```
   return axios({
      method: "get",
      url: URL,
      responseType: "blob",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return {
          ...val,
          blob: response.data,
        };
      })
      .catch((_) => {
        onError(val);
      });
```

After that i store it in indexDB using Dexie.

```
  const { id } = dataToSave;
  return db.files.put(dataToSave, id);
```

I have file in db like blob
[image]

Next i want to save it like so:
download(myBlob, title, mimeType);
i try using filesaver,downloadjs or manualy

```
  const { title, blob, mimeType } = material;
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  a.href = url;

  // the filename you want
  a.download = title;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }, 1000);
```

It will download file only right after i download it to blob (browser session).
When i refresh page i get error `WebkitBlobResource:1`.

Any workaround of problem ? To either download file (pdf,html) or open it in new or same tab.

Answer (score 0):

For now store data as arraybuffer, not blob works.